# Finding where two histograms cross paths - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, histogram

I am generating two histograms using the [histogram](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html;jsessionid=52ee3f37a1fe36a4f690bcd4a818#buhzm_z-1-h) function from Matlab that are both normalized using the `probability` argument.

However, once I generate two histograms as shown below, I'd like to be able to find the exact point at which the histograms would cross paths, assuming the histograms were drawn using lines instead of bars. Unfortunately, this form of histogram doesn't allow for lines, it just has bars. There is a `hist` function which can be manipulated in Matlab to draw a histogram as lines instead of bars, however, it doesn't easily normalize.

Hence, ideally, I'd like to use `histogram()` to plot the 2 histograms and find where they cross. See image below:

[image]

Here's an example of how the graphs can be created:

```
x = randn(2000,1);
y = 1 + randn(5000,1);
h1 = histogram(x);
hold on
h2 = histogram(y);
h1.Normalization = 'probability';
h1.BinWidth = 0.25;
h2.Normalization = 'probability';
h2.BinWidth = 0.25;
```

Now from here, I want to find the point where the two histograms cross paths. Note, the intersection value is the intersection (in the mathematical sense). This is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for the x coordinate of where the two histograms cross at their outer boundaries. For example, in the attached image, the answer would be ~2.5.

Comment: If the bars are the same width and centered in the same values then its relatively eas, just iterate over all bars and compare them to their matching. Otherwise, you are in "very long code, you need to try something yourself before asking" waters. Can you show a [mcve] of how you generate these histograms?

Comment: And how do you get intersection at 0.66? x-axis is 2.something and y-axis 0.27ish.

Comment: @kkuilla ignore the intersection value. Thats the intersection of the two histograms, not the point at which the lines cross, if that makes sense.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I've added some code, does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example data, with a simple modification:

```
x = randn(2000,1);
y = 1 + randn(5000,1);
h1 = histogram(x);
hold on
h2 = histogram(y);
h1.Normalization = 'probability';
h1.BinWidth = 0.25;
h1.BinLimits=[min([x(:); y(:)]) max([x(:); y(:)])];

h2.Normalization = 'probability';
h2.BinWidth = 0.25;
h2.BinLimits=[min([x(:); y(:)]) max([x(:); y(:)])];


data1=h1.Values;
data2=h2.Values;
intersection_value=find(data2>data1,1); % this is the index, bad variable name
```

Comment: Hmm, this gives me a different answer than expected. When I ran this, I get an intersection value of ~15 everytime. However, the paths clearly cross [0,1]. I've updated my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: @Jonathan the intersection is the index, not the value. Perhaps I mislead you with the variable name. The intersected value is between `data2(intersection_value-1)` and `data2(intersection_value)`

Comment: Would be interesting to see the plot

Comment: @kkuilla the plot is almost the same of what OP gave, just with ensured bin overlap. The answer is just and index so not plotable.